# excel, combine two vba worksheet change events?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run multiple worksheet change events, but my second macro doesn't seem to be working when *macro 1* is also present. *macro 1* however does work.

I have tried combining the two together but still no luck, can anyone please show me where I am going wrong?

macro 1

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = Range("CA8").Column Then

 Dim Email_Subject, Email_Send_From, Email_Send_To, _
 Email_Cc, Email_Bcc, Email_Body As String
 Dim Mail_Object, Mail_Single As Variant
 Email_Subject = "New Supplier Set-Up Confirmation"
 Email_Send_From = "purchasing@hewden.co.uk"
 Email_Send_To = Range("AF" & ActiveCell.Row)
 Email_Cc = "purchasing@hewden.co.uk"
 Email_Bcc = ""
 Email_Body = "Dear " & Range("AE" & ActiveCell.Row) & "," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "This is to confirm that the following supplier was set-up on AX, on " & Range("CB" & ActiveCell.Row) & "." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Supplier Name: " & Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row) & vbNewLine & "Supplier Number: " & Range("F" & ActiveCell.Row) & vbNewLine & "Supplier Status: " & Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Kind Regards," & vbNewLine & "The Purchasing Team"
 On Error GoTo debugs
 Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set Mail_Single = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)
 With Mail_Single
 .Subject = "New Supplier Set-Up Confirmation"
 .to = Range("AF" & ActiveCell.Row)
 .CC = "purchasing@hewden.co.uk"
 .BCC = ""
 .Body = Email_Body
 .Send
 End With
debugs:
 If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description



End If
End If
End Sub
```

macro 2:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change2(ByVal Target As Range)
 If ActiveCell.Address(False, False) = "CD8" Then

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "Dear Sumayra," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Please would you complete the bank details set-up for the following supplier." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Supplier Name: " & Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row) & vbNewLine & _
              "Supplier Number: " & Range("F" & ActiveCell.Row) & vbNewLine & _
              "Supplier Status: " & Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Kind Regards," & vbNewLine & _
              "Automated Purchasing Email"

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = "sumayra.idoo@hewden.co.uk"
        .CC = "purchasing@hewden.co.uk"
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "New Supplier Bank Details Set-Up"
        .Body = strbody
        'You can add a file like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing


End If
End Sub
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = Range("CA8").Column Then

     Dim Email_Subject, Email_Send_From, Email_Send_To, _
     Email_Cc, Email_Bcc, Email_Body As String
     Dim Mail_Object, Mail_Single As Variant
     Email_Subject = "New Supplier Set-Up Confirmation"
     Email_Send_From = "purchasing@hewden.co.uk"
     Email_Send_To = Range("AF" & ActiveCell.Row)
     Email_Cc = "purchasing@hewden.co.uk"
     Email_Bcc = ""
     Email_Body = "Dear " & Range("AE" & ActiveCell.Row) & "," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "This is to confirm that the following supplier was set-up on AX, on " & Range("CB" & ActiveCell.Row) & "." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Supplier Name: " & Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row) & vbNewLine & "Supplier Number: " & Range("F" & ActiveCell.Row) & vbNewLine & "Supplier Status: " & Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Kind Regards," & vbNewLine & "The Purchasing Team"
     On Error GoTo debugs
     Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
     Set Mail_Single = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)
     With Mail_Single
     .Subject = "New Supplier Set-Up Confirmation"
     .to = Range("AF" & ActiveCell.Row)
     .CC = "purchasing@hewden.co.uk"
     .BCC = ""
     .Body = Email_Body
     .Send
     End With
debugs:
     If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description


    If ActiveCell.Address(False, False) = "CD8" Then

        Dim OutApp As Object
        Dim OutMail As Object
        Dim strbody As String

        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        strbody = "Dear Sumayra," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                  "Please would you complete the bank details set-up for the following supplier." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                  "Supplier Name: " & Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row) & vbNewLine & _
                  "Supplier Number: " & Range("F" & ActiveCell.Row) & vbNewLine & _
                  "Supplier Status: " & Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                  "Kind Regards," & vbNewLine & _
                  "Automated Purchasing Email"

        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .to = "sumayra.idoo@hewden.co.uk"
            .CC = "purchasing@hewden.co.uk"
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "New Supplier Bank Details Set-Up"
            .Body = strbody
            'You can add a file like this
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            .Send   'or use .Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0

        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing



    End If


    End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell for sure not seeing your worksheet, but I expect `If ActiveCell.Address(False, False) = "CD8"` causes problem. `ActiveCell` returns Range that is active **after** change. So for example when you change A1 cell and hit enter, Change event will be triggered, and ActiveCell will be A2. To check if it was A1, you need to use `Target` that is supplied by the event.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Macro1 Target
    Macro2 Target
end sub

Private Sub Macro1(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = Range("CA8").Column Then

 Dim Email_Subject, Email_Send_From, Email_Send_To, _
 Email_Cc, Email_Bcc, Email_Body As String
 Dim Mail_Object, Mail_Single As Variant
 Email_Subject = "New Supplier Set-Up Confirmation"
 Email_Send_From = "purchasing@hewden.co.uk"
 Email_Send_To = Range("AF" & ActiveCell.Row)
 Email_Cc = "purchasing@hewden.co.uk"
 Email_Bcc = ""
 Email_Body = "Dear " & Range("AE" & ActiveCell.Row) & "," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "This is to confirm that the following supplier was set-up on AX, on " & Range("CB" & ActiveCell.Row) & "." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Supplier Name: " & Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row) & vbNewLine & "Supplier Number: " & Range("F" & ActiveCell.Row) & vbNewLine & "Supplier Status: " & Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Kind Regards," & vbNewLine & "The Purchasing Team"
 On Error GoTo debugs
 Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set Mail_Single = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)
 With Mail_Single
 .Subject = "New Supplier Set-Up Confirmation"
 .to = Range("AF" & ActiveCell.Row)
 .CC = "purchasing@hewden.co.uk"
 .BCC = ""
 .Body = Email_Body
 .Send
 End With
debugs:
 If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description



End If
End If
End Sub


Private Sub Macro2(ByVal Target As Range)
 If ActiveCell.Address(False, False) = "CD8" Then

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "Dear Sumayra," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Please would you complete the bank details set-up for the following supplier." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Supplier Name: " & Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row) & vbNewLine & _
              "Supplier Number: " & Range("F" & ActiveCell.Row) & vbNewLine & _
              "Supplier Status: " & Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Kind Regards," & vbNewLine & _
              "Automated Purchasing Email"

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = "sumayra.idoo@hewden.co.uk"
        .CC = "purchasing@hewden.co.uk"
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "New Supplier Bank Details Set-Up"
        .Body = strbody
        'You can add a file like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing


End If
End Sub
```